# How To Iterate A String In F#?

Tags: string, f#

I've got the following F# code:

```
//Array iter version
let toSecureString (s:string) =
    let sString = new SecureString()
    s |> Array.iter (fun cl -> sString.AppendChar cl)
    sString
```

I'm trying to convert a .Net string to a .Net SecureString.  When I try to compile I get a Type Mismatch error:

```
stdin(60,10): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    string -> 'a
but given a
    'b [] -> unit
The type 'string' does not match the type ''a []'
```

If I don't specify the type of s, this is the type signature I see:

```
val toSecureString : char [] -> SecureString
```

But since I don't want to have to manually create an array of chars for the argument each time, it seems like I am missing something.  How can I make this code work with a string parameter being passed in?

If it makes a difference I'm testing on F# 2.0 (Build 4.0.40219.1).

Any hints welcome.  If this has already been asked and answered, post a link in the comments and I'll close this question.

Comment: Why are you using a `SecureString` at all? If you already have a `string`, then copying it to `SecureString` won't add any security, I think. That's probably why there is no `AppendString()`.

Comment: I'm using a SecureString because the Windows API requires a SecureString.

Comment: Wow, guys, three excellent answers.  Wish I could select all of them as the "accepted answer"

Comment: I now have 5 or 6 different ways to transform a string into a SecureString.  I'm going to do some profiling and a bit of other testing and see if there's any good reason to prefer any of them over the others.  Blog post coming!

Comment: Aren't you disposing `sString` before you return it?

Comment: You know I had considered that @Lee; in FP, you're usually returning a _copy_ of a local value anyway--that whole immutable by default thing. But it may be an issue and if it is I'll simply change it to a "let". I was more intersted in why Array.iter wasn't working for me.

Comment: You know @Lee, I belive you're right.  Minor issue; I'll fix my code sample above so no one else makes that error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `Seq.iter`, not `Array.iter`, because strings are `char seq`s but not `char[]`s.

Comment: Thanks kvb.  Knew I was missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5):

To manipulate a string as a `char seq`, one can use [String module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353758.aspx).  This works:

```
let toSecureString s =
    let sString = new SecureString()
    String.iter sString.AppendChar s
    sString
```

Comment: Thanks @pad I was unaware of that option.

Comment: Actually, I prefer using String module to Seq module to avoid type annotation :).

Comment: Sorry @pad--what type annotation?  If I use Seq.iter, I don't need a type specification on s or cl in the code above.

Comment: I mean to avoid explicitly saying that `s` is `string` rather than `seq<char>`. And you don't have to use lambda, you can pass `sString.AppendChar` directly.

Comment: Oh--I see what you're saying now. That's a good point.  Thanks.

Comment: Of course, if you use `Seq.iter` and drop the type annotation, then the function will work on any sequence of characters, not just on strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this:

```
SecureString(&&s.ToCharArray().[0], s.Length)
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel--a third approach to this.  I've got another approach which I didn't post.